# Match/assign text value to an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

A short javasctipt/jquery script to match/assign the text string value with the html entity unicode value eg. '&#58880'.

For example take 5 icons that where their unicode starts from `&#58880;`

- `&#58880;` (icon displaying a basketball)
- `&#58881;` (icon displaying a tennis ball)
- `&#58882;` (icon displaying a cricket ball)
- `&#58883;` (icon displaying a volley ball)
- `&#58884;` (icon displaying a base ball)

The html would be something like this (Note: They can appear in any order at any time.)

```
<p><span data-icon="&#58883;"></span>Volleyball</p>
<p><span data-icon="&#58884;"></span>Baseball</p>
<p><span data-icon="&#58882;"></span>Cricket</p>
<p><span data-icon="&#58881;"></span>Tennis</p>
<p><span data-icon="&#58880;"></span>Basketball</p>
```

Need a way so that whenever the text string value appears (eg.Basketball) it knows to insert the 'data-icon' dynamically and knows what its data-icon value is (eg.'&#58880') etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Here is a fiddle for your reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/47kj4zzu/1/

**HTML**

```
 <div id="sports">
        <p>Volleyball</p>
        <p>Baseball</p>
        <p>Cricket</p>
        <p>Tennis</p>
        <p>Basketball</p>
    </div>
```

**JQuery/Javascript**

```
var icons = [
    {
        match: 'volleyball',
        unicode: '&#58883;'
    },
        {
        match: 'baseball',
        unicode: '&#58884;'
    },
    {
        match: 'cricket',
        unicode: '&#58882;'
    },
    {
        match: 'tennis',
        unicode: '&#58881;'
    },
    {
        match: 'basketball',
        unicode: '&#58880;'
    }  
];

var $sports = $('#sports').children('p');

$sports.each(function(){

    var $ele = $(this);    

    $.each(icons, function(){

        if($ele.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.match.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
        {
            $ele.prepend('<span data-icon="'+this.unicode+'"></span>');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Each <p> is already being generated by .php. All I need is a way to insert the data-icon="**html entity unicode here**" (ie. not the whole string). Hope that makes sense. If you can, could you update the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment @jennas. What you've done is what I am after. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that maps the game type to the html entity code.

For purpose of demonstration, I wrapped below example in a select tag that allows you to select the game type and see the value inserted into a div.

```
var obj = {'volleyball':'&#58883;','baseball':'&#58883;','cricket':'&#58883;','tennis':'&#58883;','basketball':'&#58883;'};

$('#sel').change(function(){
    var tmp = $(this).val();
    var tmp2 = tmp.toLowerCase();

    $('#result').append('<p><span data-icon="'+obj[tmp2]+'"></span>' +tmp+ '</p>');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0qpxww8j/1/)

---

This is the core of the code:

```
var = '<p><span data-icon="'+obj[tmp2]+'"></span>' +tmp+ '</p>';
```